# Unboxing of 'perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)' may produce 'NullPointerException'

Tags: android, runtime-permissions, unboxing

I am seeing this warning after updating my project to the latest 30 (buildToolsVersion "30.0.2").
How to resolve this warning?

onRequestPermissionsResult code as follows ::

```
switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {

                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();

                perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

                // Fill with actual results from user
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                        perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);

                    if ((perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    ) {
                        // do some task
                    } else {

                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                            showDialogOK(getResources().getString(R.string.some_req_permissions));
                        } else {
                            explain(getResources().getString(R.string.open_settings));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

            default:
                break;
        }
```

Comment: could you provide the check permission close from your code !

Comment: @El.MENSI code added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting an object of a wrapper type (Integer) to its corresponding primitive (int) value is called unboxing, as per the [official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) of Autoboxing and Unboxing. When you try to unbox a value that can possibly be null, this warning of a possible NullPointerException shows up.

To get rid of this warning, using `getInt()` instead of `get()` should help. You can also add a null check on the value too.

Based on the provided code in the edits, use `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission()` instead of trying to fetch a possible null value of `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` from `params` HashMap. Use the following code snippet if required:

```java
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
  // do some task
} else {
  ...
}
```

Comment: getInt() is not found, also I have added some code from onRequestPermissionsResult

Comment: I've added the recommended way of avoiding this warning & doing the same task in the code snippet after seeing your edits @AndroidGuy